# Why is my chai-as-promised rejected method not working?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I use mocha, chai, and chai-as-promised.
The test should fail, but it doesn't, I don't know what's wrong, any suggestions?

```js
const { describe, it } = require('mocha')
const chai = require('chai')
const { expect } = require('chai')
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')

chai.use(chaiAsPromised)

describe('test', () => {
    it('must be rejected', async () => {
        expect(Promise.resolve('success')).to.rejected
    })
})
```

[image: Test Result]

I tried to test a promise that should be rejected and the test should fail, but the test was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Chai as Promised docs](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/)

> Notice: either return or notify(done) must be used with promise assertions. This can be a slight departure from the existing format of assertions being used on a project or by a team. Those other assertions are likely synchronous and thus do not require special handling.

> The most powerful extension provided by Chai as Promised is the eventually property. With it, you can transform any existing Chai assertion into one that acts on a promise

You can use `async / await` or `.then(() => {})` to include multiple promises in a test.

These four tests will fail:

```js
const { describe, it } = require('mocha');
const chai = require('chai');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe('test', () => {
  it('must be rejected (1)', () => {
    return expect(Promise.resolve('success')).to.eventually.be.rejected;
  });

  it('must be rejected (2)', (done) => {
    expect(Promise.resolve('success')).to.eventually.be.rejected.notify(done);
  });

  it('must be rejected (3)', async () => {
    await expect(Promise.resolve('success1')).to.eventually.be.fulfilled;
    return expect(Promise.resolve('success2')).to.eventually.be.rejected;
  });

  it('must be rejected (4)', () => {
    return expect(Promise.resolve('success1')).to.eventually.be.fulfilled.then(
      () => expect(Promise.resolve('success2')).to.eventually.be.rejected
    );
  });
});
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-a7t3tx?file=index.js

Comment: Thank you very much; I didn't notice it.